# Rent a surf board for one month in Bali

Tags: rental, indonesia, bali, surfing

I want to rent a surf board for 1 month in Bali.

What kind of price should I expect?

The daily price is usually 100'000 IDR in Canggu. So I expect a discount when renting for 1 month, I just don't know how much of a discount.

Comment: What kind of 'board' are we talking about? Generally, shortboards go for a cheaper rate than longboards. For stand-up pedalling (SUP) boards (again, they come in different flavours) you can often double to triple the price of one of the aforementioned. In my experience, on Bali, the discount you get for longer-term rentals is usually directly related to your haggling skills. With that in mind, I think it's going to be difficult to get a definitive answer (unless a local shop owner happens to read your question here and is willing to offer you a deal :)).

Comment: I mean a regular surf board, one you stand up on. NOT a short board nor a SUP. I disagree though regarding prices. There definitely is a price range for monthly rentals in Bali for many things (Accommodation, scooter, and so on). And to make the question more specific, I mentioned my location (Canggu) and the usual daily price here (which everyone knows).

Comment: Me think it would be easier to just buy the board on site and leave it there when you come back.

Comment: @Max could be yeah. As a learner you keep switching board though. Once you know what board you like, buying one is probably the best option.

Comment: There is a Facebook page called "Bali surfers buy and sell".  The current top post shows boards for sale ranging from Rp180,000 to Rp5,500,00

Answer (score 3):

The best offer I got so far was **1.8 millions IDR** for renting a surf board one month in Bali (Canggu).

The nice part of this deal is that the owner of the shop told me he could not do a better deal as it is now the high season (August) but he'd **allow me to change board every week** if I need to (as I'm learning).

I'll update this answer if I get any other interesting quotes.

Comment: Please do. Also, I'd like to do the same during a visit to learn surfing. Please do share his contact info if he has a website / Facebook / or email - After asking him ofcourse. 
Also, where are you learning? What part of Kuta? Which spots?

Comment: I'm learning in Canggu, at Batu Bolong spot. Kuta is also good for learning but it's packed with tourists and prices for everything are higher. Buying a surf board may be a cheaper option in the end..

Comment: When I looked only I only found info about Kuta as a beginners spot etc. But someone told me its a crappy crowded drunk tourist trap so better to find elsewhere. PS: How could I keep in touch with you so as to plan my trip ?

Comment: Yeah, look at Canggu, much less tourists and very nice. Look at Bukit peninsula for other nice spots.

Comment: I just posted this here: If you have any notes/ thoughts do share :) http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9316/inexpensive-spots-season-to-stay-1-2-3-months-for-newbie-to-learn-surfing

Answer (score -5):

Hi all you guys you can just rent my board for 900k for a month, you can also change your board during your rental term! I'm located at Kuta!!

Comment: I have edited the post so it is not a spam post anymore. Please do not post more details.